# No provider for "framework:requirejs"! (Resolving: framework:requirejs)

Tags: unit-testing, requirejs, karma-jasmine

I've downloaded [this karma-jasmine sample code](https://github.com/kjbekkelund/karma-requirejs/) , I've googled a lot and it seems that it must work.

But when ever I run

```
   karma start karma.conf.js
```

it gives me this error :

```
 /Users/xe4me/www/html/apache/requirejs-     karma/node_modules/karma/node_modules/di/lib/injector.js:9
  throw error('No provider for "' + name + '"!');
        ^
 Error: No provider for "framework:jasmine"! (Resolving: framework:jasmine)
at error (/Users/xe4me/www/html/apache/requirejs-karma/node_modules/karma/node_modules/di/lib/injector.js:22:68)
at Object.parent.get (/Users/xe4me/www/html/apache/requirejs-karma/node_modules/karma/node_modules/di/lib/injector.js:9:13)
at get (/Users/xe4me/www/html/apache/requirejs-karma/node_modules/karma/node_modules/di/lib/injector.js:54:19)
at /Users/xe4me/www/html/apache/requirejs-karma/node_modules/karma/lib/server.js:29:14
at Array.forEach (native)
at start (/Users/xe4me/www/html/apache/requirejs-karma/node_modules/karma/lib/server.js:28:21)
at invoke (/Users/xe4me/www/html/apache/requirejs-karma/node_modules/karma/node_modules/di/lib/injector.js:75:15)
at Object.exports.start (/Users/xe4me/www/html/apache/requirejs-karma/node_modules/karma/lib/server.js:307:12)
at Object.exports.run (/Users/xe4me/www/html/apache/requirejs-karma/node_modules/karma/lib/cli.js:220:27)
at requireCliAndRun (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma-cli/bin/karma:44:16)
```

I've also did below method , with no luck:

```
 npm install karma-requirejs --save-dev
```

I've done everything right , but still no luck , and also there are some questions in SO that seems to be the same as mine , I've tried all the answers , but still no luck ;

any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: You have to `npm install karma-jasmine`.

Answer (score 8):

You need `requirejs` & `karma-requirejs`:

```
npm install requirejs --save-dev
npm install karma-requirejs --save-dev
```

After that make sure to configure Karma as described in "[Run Karma with Require.js](https://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/plus/requirejs.html)".

**Minimal Working Example (generated by `karma init`)**

**karma.conf.js**

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', 'requirejs'],
    files: [
      {pattern: 'dest/main/**/*.js', included: false},
      {pattern: 'test/**/*Spec.js', included: false},
      'test-main.js'
    ],
    exclude: [],
    preprocessors: {},
    reporters: ['progress'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: false,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false,
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
};
```

**test-main.js**

```
var allTestFiles = [];
var TEST_REGEXP = /(spec|test)\.js$/i;

// Get a list of all the test files to include
Object.keys(window.__karma__.files).forEach(function(file) {
  if (TEST_REGEXP.test(file)) {
    // Normalize paths to RequireJS module names.
    // If you require sub-dependencies of test files to be loaded as-is (requiring file extension)
    // then do not normalize the paths
    var normalizedTestModule = file.replace(/^\/base\/|\.js$/g, '');
    allTestFiles.push(normalizedTestModule);
  }
});

require.config({
  // Karma serves files under /base, which is the basePath from your config file
  baseUrl: '/base',

  // dynamically load all test files
  deps: allTestFiles,

  // we have to kickoff jasmine, as it is asynchronous
  callback: window.__karma__.start
});
```

Comment: But still its not working.. Any update regarding latest update of karma

Comment: thanks, the help message should really say `Did you forget to install it?
  npm install requirejs karma-requirejs`

Answer (score 1):

Try to add "karma-requirejs" to the plugins array in karma.conf.js

```
...

plugins: [             
            'karma-jasmine',                      
            'karma-chrome-launcher',                
            'karma-jasmine-html-reporter',
            'karma-webpack',
            'karma-requirejs'
        ],


// Continuous Integration mode
// if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
singleRun: false, 

...
```